# Why does thread2 wait for thread1 to end?

Tags: c, multithreading

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>

#define NR_LOOP 10000

static int resource = 0;

static void *thread1_function();
static void *thread2_function();

int main(void){

  pthread_t thread1,thread2;

  pthread_create(&thread1,NULL,*thread1_function,NULL);
  pthread_create(&thread2,NULL,*thread2_function,NULL); 

  pthread_join(thread1,NULL);
  pthread_join(thread2,NULL);

  printf("The value of the resource is: %d\n",resource);
  return 0;
}

static void *thread1_function(){

  for(int i = 0; i < NR_LOOP; i++){
  resource++;
  }

 return NULL;
}


static void *thread2_funcion(){

  for(int i = 0; i < NR_LOOP; i++){
  resource--;
  }

return NULL;
}
```

I'm trying a simple thread code to put into practice what they taught me in class, the problem is that thread2 waits for the thread1 to finish to run, the idea is that both run and the result is different from

Comment: Is your compiler optimizing those loops away?

Comment: I correct the title here: Why does thread 2 wait for thread1 to end?

Comment: And are you expecting it to print out something other than 0 at the end? (Unless `resource` is an `_Atomic int` I suppose it could...). And how do you know that your first thread finishes before the second runs, anyways? Nothing in that code checks for any such thing.

Comment: What makes you think that thread2 waits? The `join()` calls ensure that your main thread will not execute the printf(...) until _both_ thread1 and thread2 have finished. And, because of what @Shawn alluded to, those threads might finish their work _much_ more quickly than you're expecting them to do.

Comment: sorry people, the code works excellent, the value of the constant was too small and as they said they were running too fast, to visualize it increase the constant to 10,000,000

Answer (score -1):

because this function is blocking. if we open man we read the following:

> The pthread_join() function waits for the thread specified by thread to terminate. If that thread has already terminated, then pthread_join() returns immediately. The thread specified by thread must be joinable.

Comment: The question is asking why thread 2 waits for thread 1, not why the parent thread waits.